# Aging with bestow curse, gain immunity to aging penalties, and then Antimagic Field?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

If I age myself with the [*bestow curse*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/bestowCurse.htm) spell (*Book of Vile Darkness*, alternative curses) to have the attribute adjustments, subsequently gain the benefit of "immunity to aging attacks and doesn't suffer the effects of old age (Any penalties already incurred stay in effect)" and then walk through an Antimagic Field and out the other side, will I gain the age bonuses while ignoring the penalties?

For clarification the immunity to aging benefit comes from a supernatural ability, so it would also be suppressed in the Antimagic Field.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Aging is listed as an alternative curse in Book of Vile Darkness so I'm pretty sure he'll be okay with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When walking in**

Well, if the curse is suppressed (by being in antimagic in this case), you become young again. Thus you wouldn't have the age penalties or bonuses.

If you were to be actually old, any magical ability to get rid aging penalties would also be suppressed. So that supernatural ability that grants immunity to aging would not work in antimagic anyway.

**When walking out again**

The moment you leave, both effects will start working again. Thus you'd be old again due to the curse, and you'd ignore the penalties due to the immunity to aging. This is assuming the duration of those effects hasn't expired (and I'm assuming that they're both permanent, so this shouldn't be a problem). Just like they would work if you never entered the antimagic field.

[Antimagic field:](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/antimagicField.htm)

> An antimagic field suppresses any spell or magical effect used within, brought into, or cast into the area, but does not dispel it. Time spent within an antimagic field counts against the suppressed spell’s duration.

Comment: I'm asking what happens after you leave the antimagic field.  Do you regain the age categories while simultaneously having immunity from the penalties?

Comment: I misunderstood the question, updated it

Comment: Apologies, I forgot a crucial aspect. I retain penalties I've already incurred due to age as part of the benefit

Comment: Well the curse and immunity come back at exactly the same time (the moment you step out of the antimagic field). I'd say that therefor the immunity applies to the aging. I don't have RAW on that, in fact I don't think the rules cover that very specific scenario (I hope I get corrected on this). So it would be a gm call

Comment: @Snappie wrote "Just like they would work if you never entered the antimagic field." I think you're missing the critical point of OP's question. OP specifies that for the magic-aging-immunity "Any penalties already incurred stay in effect" So, in the original order, the anti-aging does not help since the aging came first. Then, the point is that the anti-magic cancels both out, then they both come back at the same time to avoid the "already incurred stay in effect" clause. The question is essentially similar to "aging came first, so I'm screwed. Can I do a clever fix like so..."

Comment: @Aaron there is actually some ambiguity about that. Both the curse and the effect that suppresses age penalties are gone. the character is young again while in the antimagic field. Then when stepping out of the antimagic both effects reactivate at exactly the same time. Therefor the phrase "Any penalties already incurred stay in effect" raises ambiguity, as there were no age penalties prior to the reactivation of the aging curse.

Comment: @Snappie Agree. Though, if we did split hairs with our rules-lawyering, and if we agreed that the two effects returned at the exact same time, then one could easily argue that "already incurred" does not apply anymore since that would require the penalty to apply _before_, where now they are applying at the exact same time, so the penalty did not come "before" this time. So, even if I rules-lawyered, I would rule in OP's favor. However, I would prefer to go with rule of cool on this one: if the players figure out a cool and clever way to do something, let it be so. Let there be fun.

Comment: Does it make any difference that the alternative curse from the *Book of Vile Darkness* only *effectively* — as opposed to *actually* — ages the creature?

Comment: @Aaron: Beyond the rule of cool, isn't there a rule that let a player choose in which order effects apply when simultaneous effects are to be applied, similar to how a player can choose in which order to apply bonuses when they have several?

Comment: @MatthieuM. If there is such a rule, I do not remember it. However, I would not be surprised if such a rule exists - that sounds reasonable. Good catch; if you can verify that, you will have an excellent answer to provide.